# how to see modern view in Sencha Ext.js Universal application

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd

Im using sencha ext-6.5.3.57 and creating a universal application using the below command.
`sencha -sdk C:\Users\AANANTHA\sencha-sdks\ext-6.5.3.57 generate app MyApp`

Once i build and launch the app using sencha app watch command i can see and modify only classic view , if i change anything in modern view its not reflecting in the app.

Please suggest as i'm new to sencha.

I tried changing the code in classic view and modern view js files .But i can see changes reflecting only in classic view .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define a condition to select a specific profile to show to the user.
If you have just made a fresh universal app, this condition is located in `index.html`, in `Ext.beforeLoad` you'll see the profile is set based on the url.

So for testing purposes you can change your profile putting `?classic` or `?modern` at the end of your url, if you need or want to create other profiles, you can define them in `app.json` in the `builds` part.